# Only select text between parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a code in `php`, and I want to work with `regular expressions` so this is the file I have

```
(1) DF  Mikael Nilsson                     ##   27, Panathinaikos (GRE)
(3)  DF  Olof Mellberg                      ##   64, Aston Villa (ENG)
```

So I have made myself a `regular expression` that is this one `#\W[A-Z]{3}\S#` but the outcome is `(ENG)` and I want the outcome te be only `ENG` and `GRE` so only the text inside the parentheses.

I hope there is someone who can help me,
Thanks for the afford

Comment: Simply put grouping parentheses around the inner part: `#\W([A-Z]{3})\S#`, then you will get an extra entry in your array of matches with only the contents inside.

Comment: @CBroe this still select the parentheses..

Comment: As I said, yes – you will get the _whole_ match first, but the _inner_ match as a separate value (extra entry in the resulting array).

Comment: @CBroe Oke! Thank you it worked as you told me

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:\()([A-Z]{3})(?:\))
```

When matching that, you should capture a *group* from it, which is only the letters.

Comment: No need for the non-capturing goups here... the result is the same !!

Comment: This code is still selecting everyting even the parentheses

Comment: @mr13018 using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), the result is stored in `$matches[1]`

Comment: @mr13018 then your result is in `$match[1]`!

Comment: @mr13018 OR, If you dont want to change much in your code, then use `#\W\K[A-Z]{3}(?=\S)#`

Comment: Thank you @Enissay this is the answer to all the problems I'm realy sorry but my php is not that great. sorry to bother you :(

Comment: @iostream.h Sorry for hijacking your post... Feel free to update your answer accordingly so it gets accepted <3